# Will exchange sync email across multiple outlook instances on different machines?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync

I've got a desktop PC(Windows 7) with outlook 2010 installed.  I've also got a laptop (windows 7) with outlook 2010 installed on it.

My email account is managed by an exchange server instance.

With respect to email, what changes should I expect to be propagated between these two instances?

For example:

- deleting an email on one

  - will the email be deleted on the other instance?
- moving an email to another folder

  - will the other instance move the email to the folder? What if the folder doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes, assuming you've made no client-side changes, you should see all changes synchronised across all devices and clients.

Comment: @RandolphWest what sort of client side changes are you thinking of?  We've got my described setup currently not updating properly and we're not sure what caused it to stop syncing.

Comment: Client-side rules can affect this. Normally with Exchange mail, I nuke the client profile and start over if it's misbehaving. Easier to troubleshoot with a known status. Be careful you're not killing PST files though.

Answer (score 3):

When Outlook runs against Exchange using the native connection (not IMAP or POP3), you have a "copy" of the mailbox stored in the .ost file. If you have multiple instances, they each sync with Exchange.

I have several laptops, several desktops a phone and a tablet, they all have identical copies of my mailbox. If I send on a phone, then it is visible in the sent items of all of the copies of Outlook (it would be visible on the phone and tablet if I synced sent items), if I receive an email, it is visible in all copies of Outlook and the phone and tablet.

Comment: I think we're in agreement here. Outlook will deliver email to each instance properly, what I'm trying to figure out is if it should propagate changes made in one outlook instance to all others.  As per my example, if I move an email in one instance, will exchange be notified and update the other.

Comment: If you move the mail in the context of the server, yes. If you move it into a PST, then it will vanish on the other clients.